# websocket и безопасность отправки/приёма сообщений

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

**Какая лучшая практика в организации безопасности при работе с вебсокетами?**

Алгоритм действий, как у меня сейчас используется вебсокет:

- Отправляем какое-то событие по ajax(допустим, отправка сообщения в
  чат)
- В случае успешного завершения работы нам приходит ответ от сервера + сообщение
- Отправляем это сообщение через вебсокет
- Вебсокет отправляет это сообщение ко всем подключенным клиентам
- Выводим сообщение

Этот способ работает так, как мне нужно. 
Зачем тут ajax запрос, а не напрямую через сокет отправка? Потому что мне не удалось подключить основной класс проекта к вебсокету(работа с базой данных и прочие функции), постоянно время от времени скрипт сервера вебсокета обрывался и всё завершалось, не знаю с чем это связано. Хотя через ajax класс прекрасно работает всегда.

За безопасность ajax скрипта я уверен, всё точно хорошо обрабатывается. 
А вот с вебсокетом проблема: если злоумышленник отправит сообщение вебсокету в нужном формате, то это сообщение отобразится у всех пользователей, словно оно было отправлено...Как-то можно избежать этого?

Может есть какой-то способ как передать сообщение из одного файла проекта в запущенный файл-сервер вебсокета?

---

**UPD**

Движок сайта самописный, строится на классическом mvc.

Всё идёт через index.php, роутинг и прочее. 
Файл вебсокета сервера - server.php

Доступ к нему осуществляется по адресу site.ru/ws

Я не знаю как мне из терминала запустить site.ru/ws чтобы всё работало, а без этого не выйдет подключить все нужные классы, если запускать файл server.php(в котором находится непосредственно логика вебсокет сервера) напрямую, то соответственно нет доступа к базе данных и основным модулям проекта.

---

**UPD2**

Отправить сообщение на порт или в работающий скрипт вебсокета из PHP в принципе невозможно? Это бы решило все проблемы с безопасностью, я бы после ajax`a напрямую отправлял сообщение в вебсокет, а он бы уже отсылал всё клиентам, а не наоборот.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42320/discussion-on-question-by-floyat-websocket-----).

Comment: эту проблему я решил, но для сервера на java. фактически привязывается соединение по ws/wss к сессии и имени юзера. при приеме сообщения проверятся есть ли для данной сессии коннект по ws. если данного соответствия нет- коннект ws обрывается.

Answer (score -1):

Просто из консоли запусти свой сервер....

Например если у тебя конект сокета лежит на:

```
Socket/server.php
```

то ты должен в консоле написать:

```
cd Socket
```

а потом:

```
php server.php
```

вот ссылка на php+js `websocket`:
https://github.com/karenYerevan/Php-Socket